# Hive Complex Column Comments Missing

Tags: hive, comments, cloudera, complextype

I created a table in hive with complex column (e.g. Struct Type) with comments.
Table creation was success.
But when i try to view or describe the table, column comments are not displayed.

Create Table Is Success

```
CREATE TABLE TEST
(
    Col1                 STRING               COMMENT 'column 1',
    Col2                STRUCT <  
    Col21                      :STRING         COMMENT 'Column 2 row 1',
    Col22                      :STRING         COMMENT 'Column 2 row 2',
    Col23                      :STRING         COMMENT 'Column 2 row 3'
                              >
)
COMMENT 'Table Level comment'
```

But Describe Table does not display comments for complex column.

```
Describe Formatted TEST;

+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--+
|           col_name            |                     data_type                      |        comment        |
+-------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------+-----------------------+--+
| # col_name                    | data_type                                          | comment               |
|                               | NULL                                               | NULL                  |
| col1                          | string                                             | column 1              |
| col2                          | struct<Col21:string,Col22:string,Col23:string>     |                       |
```

Comment: Did you see a way to get this done ?